# How to handle 'The source contains no DataRows. ' error

Tags: c#, linq

The code below will throw an error:

> The source contains no DataRow

if the row is empty. How can I handle this error in code so it does not throw an exception?

```
if (dtTemSec.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grdStepDetails.DataSource = dtTemSec.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Status") != "D" && x.Field<string>("ID") == "ST" && x.Field<int>("Folder") == folder)
                    .CopyToDataTable();
    grdStepDetails.DataBind();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowStepPopup();", true);
}
else
{
    grdStepDetails.DataSource = null;
    grdStepDetails.DataBind();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowStepPopup();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
if (dtTemSec.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var table = dtTemSec;
    var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Status") != "D" && x.Field<string>("ID") == "ST" && x.Field<int>("Folder") == folder);
    var dt = rows.Any() ? rows.CopyToDataTable() : table.Clone();
    grdStepDetails.DataSource = dt;
    grdStepDetails.DataBind();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowStepPopup();", true);
}
else
{
    grdStepDetails.DataSource = null;
    grdStepDetails.DataBind();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowStepPopup();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a If condition as below.

```
if(dtTemSec != null)
{
   if(dtTemSec.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If that is the case, then put the condition after the Filter

```
if(dtTemSec != null)
    {
       if(dtTemSec.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           DataTable Temp = new DataTable();
           Temp = dtTemSec.AsEnumerable()
                                        .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Status") != "D" && x.Field<string>("ID") == "ST" && x.Field<int>("Folder") == folder)
                                        .CopyToDataTable();
           if(Temp != null)
           {
           if(Temp.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
              grdStepDetails.DataSource=Temp;
              grdStepDetails.DataBind();
              ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowStepPopup();", true);
           }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @sai..Thanks for your response. The 'dtTemSec' always contains values ..Based on those values  I filter the datas   .grdStepDetails.DataSource = dtTemSec.AsEnumerable()
                                        .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Status") != "D" && x.Field<string>("ID") == "ST" && x.Field<int>("Folder") == folder)
                                        .CopyToDataTable();                                       If the result dosnt contains rows,it will through the error